# Android Studio - Open module from within app

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, merge

This might sound a bit messy, but it is the easiest way i could figure out. I am making an app containing both 2d and 3d screens. After hours of trying to make the 3D functionality work in Android Studio, i gave up and started making it in Unity instead..

Now I have made a sample project in Unity, exported it to Android Studio, and imported the project into my existing project, so the structure looks like this:

[image]

I have the app and the pleaseAR (haha, the Unity project) and i can run both apps on my device from the top menu inside Android Studio. But what i would like, is to switch to pleaseAR app inside of my other app. Is there a way to do this? Or any other ways to implement a Unity project into an existing Android Studio project, and open it from the app?